# How a java application should discover extensions in runtime?

Tags: java

I want to look for extension jars in a predefined directory and examine their manifest. Those which match should be loaded, those which do not - should be unloaded.

Now, I can do it a primitive way - mandate that each extension pass the name of its bootstrapper on the command line and then for each jar found in the directory try and load any of the given bootstrapper types. Something like this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar --pluginDir=c:/a/b/c --exts="classA;classB;classC"
```

Then myapp would iterate over all the files inside the `pluginDir` and try to load each of `classA`, `classB` or `classC`. Once a `classX` is successfully loaded, it is removed from the list. The search stops when either all the extensions are found and loaded or there are no more jars in the plugin dir.

A slightly more javaish approach seems to be writing something in the manifest of extension jars and check the manifest of each found jar.

Can anyone show a working code snippet of this approach or of anything better, if there is?

**EDIT**

A quote from the postgre JDBC driver README file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12480373/80002):

```
INSTALLING THE DRIVER

To install the driver, the postgresql.jar file has to be in the classpath.

ie: under LINUX/SOLARIS (the example here is my linux box):

    export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/pgsql/share/java/postgresql.jar
```

Comment: Apparently, my question is almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447699/java-spi-serviceloader-adding-multiple-jars-to-app-classpath, only I did not know about the ServiceLoader and left an option for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is [ServideLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class for this purpose. JDBC drivers are built on this principle. Hope, it helped.

Comment: Please, give an example code snippet. Also note, that the extension jars are not in the class path as it appears in the manifest of the application jar.

Comment: It is quite complex, but if you've read the JavaDoc and try Google. You may find examples like http://solitarygeek.com/java/a-simple-pluggable-java-application or http://weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2008/08/simple_dependen.html

Comment: I wish you could give an example. Still +1.

Comment: Ok 1 real world example: here is the plugin http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-jdbc-9.1-902.src.tar.gz notice the META-INF/services content and here is the "plugin loader" http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/sql/DriverManager.java.html line 502

Comment: Nope. They specifically require the driver to be in the CLASSPATH - please see an update to my question.

Comment: It is not possible to instantiate a class which is not on the CLASSPATH (except compiling it in Java, but it is an edge case). You have to firstly get it to the CLASSPATH. It is not difficult see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252893/how-do-you-change-the-classpath-within-java

Comment: But I do not know which jar is an extension jar and which is not! Does this mean I need to add all the jars in the plugin directory to the class path?